# Paste a text file from iPhone to Network Computer Programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, networking, copy-paste

**I want to paste a file (created by my iPhone app) from my iPhone to a specific folder of a LAN Computer programmatically (by Objective C). I am using Wi-Fi network and my iPhone and the computer are in the same network.**
Using my iPhone Application simulator, I can copy and paste files from one folder to another folder in the same MAC. My intension is to get the latest copy of the file from that predefined computer and paste the files of my iPhone App in that folder as well.

Comment: This wouldn't be so much pasting as it would be a file transfer. I think that creating a .txt and transferring it with some protocol (I don't do much of this kind of stuff) shouldn't be too much trouble.

Comment: in my windows server, a desktop application is running. this application takes xml file from a specified shared directory. Our existing PDA application sends file through Wi-Fi network in that directory. My task is to send the generated xml file to that place. using any kind of protocol (AFP/HTTP/FTP etc) won't help too much. But I am considering one of these approach for my alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

I can see one easy option which would be to use something like the Dropbox SDK and have a Dropbox client deployed on your computer. This isn't probably what you are looking for.

The other option is for you to write a small service on your computer which listen on a port. You iPhone app can then connect to this port and send the file. The small server app can then write the file where you need to.

The remaining point is how the iPhone can discover the computer on the network and for this you can use the Bonjour protocol: http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-networking-and-bonjour-on-iphone/ to advertise your server: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNetService_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNetService/publish

The client iPhone apps use the `NSNetServiceBrowser` class to discover the service: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNetServiceBrowser_Class/Reference/Reference.html